# How to add javadocs to a Maven build on Hudson

Tags: maven-2, hudson, javadoc

I am using Hudson 1.389 and Maven 2, and am generating javadocs as part of my build.
Javadocs are generated to: target/apidocs.
However, there is no link to them from the Hudson project page (or the module page).

My project is a multi-module Maven project, but the javadocs are only generated for one module. In that module's pom.xml, I have added this:

```
<build>
            <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                            <executions>
                                    <execution>
                                            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                                            <goals>
                                                    <goal>jar</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                    </execution>
                            </executions>
                    </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
            <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

I'd appreciate any help.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add some tidbits that may help others...

- The javadoc target is `javadoc:javadoc`.
- You can get to the job page by clicking Modules (left side above build history) and then a job name.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the `Publish javadocs` checkbox in the hudson job configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to run the install target and then the javadoc target, then Hudson picked it up automagically.

Note: the javadoc link only appeared by itself on the job page.